# Installing BaseImage throws Exception "Value out of Range"

Tags: windows-10, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

Calling `DesktopAppConverter.exe -Setup -BaseImage c:\temp\Apps\BaseImage-16299.wim` ends up with Exception

> Value outside the expected range.

I downloaded the Image from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/dac.

Here you can see the Logfile:

```
[2017-12-11T15:05:03] Log file can be found in C:\DesktopAppConverter\96ad1636-984d-42d7-9bb3-328f332db1bb\logs\DesktopAppConverterSetup.log
[2017-12-11T15:05:03] Desktop App Converter 2.1.1.release_2017-10-25_17-08_813cf2829a8823824411be7075c2d457efea7288
[2017-12-11T15:05:03] --------------------------------------------------

Checking Prerequisites

[2017-12-11T15:05:03] Checking Windows Version to ensure it meets minimum requirements
[2017-12-11T15:05:03] Minimum Windows Version requirement is met.
[2017-12-11T15:05:03] --------------------------------------------------

Running Setup

[2017-12-11T15:05:03] Checking that the Base Image file 'C:\temp\APP\BaseImage-16299.wim' exists
[2017-12-11T15:05:03] Ensuring that the Base Image file 'C:\temp\APP\BaseImage-16299.wim' is a valid windows image
[2017-12-11T15:05:04] Testing for required Windows feature enabled
[2017-12-11T15:05:05] Testing for required feature enabled...
[2017-12-11T15:05:05] Required feature is enabled. Checking if reboot is required
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Required feature is enabled.
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Required Windows feature is enabled
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Setting up expanded base image
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Deleting any old expanded base image.
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Checking if there is OS-Matching expanded base image.
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Preparing to expand base image
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Validating Base Image path: C:\temp\APP\BaseImage-16299.wim
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Checking that the Base Image file 'C:\temp\APP\BaseImage-16299.wim' exists
[2017-12-11T15:05:07] Ensuring that the Base Image file 'C:\temp\APP\BaseImage-16299.wim' is a valid windows image
[2017-12-11T15:05:08] Ensure base image matches host OS
[2017-12-11T15:05:08] Testing if base image at C:\temp\APP\BaseImage-16299.wim is compatible with your OS
[2017-12-11T15:05:08] The base image version was determined to be 10.0.16299.0
[2017-12-11T15:05:08] Your Windows version was determined to be 10.0.16299.0
[2017-12-11T15:05:08] Ignoring revision numbers
[2017-12-11T15:05:08] Expanded base image at C:\temp\APP\BaseImage-16299.wim IS compatible with your OS
[2017-12-11T15:05:08] Expanding Base Image (this may take a while)
[2017-12-11T15:12:32] Processing Expanded Base Image at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-16299
[2017-12-11T15:12:36] An error occurred converting your application. Here is the full error record: 
[2017-12-11T15:12:36] 

PowerShell Error Record:
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ProcessBaseLayer" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs."
PowerShell Stack Trace:
bei Expand-BaseImage, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\converter_util\BaseImageOps.ps1: Zeile 388
bei Setup-ExpandedImages, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Setup.ps1: Zeile 245
bei Setup-DesktopAppConverter, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Setup.ps1: Zeile 139
bei <ScriptBlock><Process>, C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1: Zeile 382
bei <ScriptBlock>, <Keine Datei>: Zeile 1

Inner Exception[0]:
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ProcessBaseLayer" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs." ---> System.ArgumentException: Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs.
     bei Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.ContainerStorage.StorageFunctions.ProcessBaseImage(String path)
     bei Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.ContainerStorage.ProcessBaseLayer(String path)
     bei CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
     --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
     bei System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
     bei System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
     bei System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
     bei System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
Inner Exception Stack Trace[0]
     bei System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
     bei System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
     bei System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
     bei System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
     bei System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()

Inner Exception[1]:
System.ArgumentException: Der Wert liegt außerhalb des erwarteten Bereichs.
     bei Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.ContainerStorage.StorageFunctions.ProcessBaseImage(String path)
     bei Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.ContainerStorage.ProcessBaseLayer(String path)
     bei CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
Inner Exception Stack Trace[1]
     bei Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.ContainerStorage.StorageFunctions.ProcessBaseImage(String path)
     bei Microsoft.Windows.ComputeVirtualization.ContainerStorage.ProcessBaseLayer(String path)
     bei CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
[2017-12-11T15:12:36] The full error record is saved in the logs at C:\DesktopAppConverter\96ad1636-984d-42d7-9bb3-328f332db1bb\logs
```

After this I found a new Folder `BaseImage-16299` under

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images". There are 12 GB Data and
>   84570 Files. But using DesktopAppConverter Fails to create a Windows
>   Store App with Exception "E_EXPANDED_BASEIMG_INVALID.
>   ExpandedBaseImage at 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-16299' > is not a Container Image.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the packages with the new [free Express edition from Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html), developed in partnership with Microsoft, its purpose is to complement the Desktop App Converter.

This tool does not need that base image, instead you can use a Hyper-V or VMware virtual machines for the conversion.

It has a GUI that allows for advanced customization of the APPX packages, without requiring you to have knowledge about the internals package schemas.

If you have any questions about it, let me know, would love to help.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team that builds Advanced Installer.*